# (Trigonometric Expression + a bit of physics) Express the maximum horizontal distance , x , travelled by the ball, in terms of v and .

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

since it told me to express the maximum horizontal distance, I thought it would make sense to make y = 0, because the ball reaches its maximum horizontal distance when the ball finally drops back down to ground level. So I continued to solve for x algebraically, but I ended up with a different answer. So can someone tell me what I did wrong?

The correct answer is:

[image]

my working out:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Expanding $\tan x$ you can see that

$$x = -\frac{v^2\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\cos^2\theta}{5} = -\frac{v^2\sin \theta\cos \theta}{5}$$

$$\implies x = -\frac{v^2\sin 2\theta}{10}$$

Comment: thanks Dhanvi, but what about the negative sign, how do I take it away?

Comment: multiply -2 instead of 2?